# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread getCurrentAppId

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

**Language**: - Java 1.7 
**Environment**: - Eclipse IDE Kepler

**Requirement**: - It is regarding fetch data from java application. I have created a web application in GAE which is working fine. Now I want to my application code should run from main and retrieve the date stored in Data Store. Need to fetch data from core java application.

```
import java.util.List; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions; 

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query query = new Query("SMS").addSort("Date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        List<Entity> customers =  datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(50));

        for(Entity e : customers){

            System.out.println("Service: - " + e.getProperty("Service") );
            System.out.println("UserName: - " + e.getProperty("UserName") );
            System.out.println("QueryString: - " + e.getProperty("QueryString") );
            System.out.println("EmailId: - " + e.getProperty("EmailId") );
            System.out.println("MobileHashFormat: - " + e.getProperty("MobileHashFormat") );
            System.out.println("Date: - " + e.getProperty("Date") );
            System.out.println("Status: - " + e.getProperty("Status") );




            }
        }
```

**Exception**: -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
>     at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:86)
>     at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:102)
>     at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.(Query.java:215)
>     at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.(Query.java:144)
>     at serive.TestGAEFile.main(TestGAEFile.java:17)

Answer (score 3):

When you try to run things from the command line, you need to understand that Google App Engine will need to do a lot of work to setup the local environment with just about enough services to even let the APIs work in the way that you want.

To facilitate testing in this local way, you will need to read up on the Local Unit Testing features. Check out https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting?csw=1 and you will need additional JARs and use a LocalTesting Helper class that setups up the environment for you.

Comment: It is not working for me because I need to fetch Entity store data from GAE. And from java application not java web application. Kindly assist

Comment: I am not sure what your exact requirement is ... but if you are planning to access data from your GAE App from any application, I suggest that you write a Web Service that allows you to access various kinds of information that you may want to pull out from a GAE App.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work from a public static void main().
It'll work from a servlet which is what I just tried when I got this same error.
Good luck.